# Why Scala allows passing null?

Tags: scala

I'm going through Scala book.

Here is example:

```scala
  def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] = {
    try {
      Some(Integer.parseInt(s.trim))
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => None
    }
  }

  val x = null
  println(toInt(x)) // < ---- why compiler does not complain about Null ?
```

`toInt` should allow only `String` as an argument, but compiler is ok with null.

Why ?
Such kind of behavior is disallowed in Rust and TypeScript.

Is there any flag or smth ?

Comment: Yep, Kotlin got this one right too. For all of the many, many things Scala did a wonderful job of, leaving `null` unchecked is very possibly the worst decision in Scala. It looks like Dotty [may have something to say about it](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/explicit-nulls.html), for what it's worth

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Kotlin at least attempted to get it right, but soon enough [found out that it's easier said than done](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/what-is-the-reason-behind-smart-cast-being-impossible-to-perform-when-referenced-class-is-in-another-module/2201); I didn't check on whether there have been any recent changes in that direction, though.

Comment: Maybe it's also worth explaining why it's different in TS and Rust. 1. TS had JS as foundation, and JS had no type system whatsoever. Therefore, TS's type system was basically a green-field project, and it had the opportunity to "do it right" from the beginning (which it did, quite successfully). This was not the case with Java, which already had `String` that included `null` etc. 2. Similarly for Rust: is had not to be compatible with any toxic legacy type annotations, so it did the right thing, and eliminated `null` as concept altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Option` can help because `Option(null) == None`

```
def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] =
  Option(s).flatMap(_.toIntOption)

toInt(null) // None
```

but usually we anticipate it with signatures like

```
def toInt(s: Option[String]): Option[Int]
```

and wrap legacy APIs that can return null with a Scala layer

```
toInt(Option(legacyJavaApi()))
```

Also linters like Wartremover could help: https://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html#null

Occasionally an initialisation [trick](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/8a2cf63ee5bad8c8c054f76464de0e10226516a0/src/library/scala/collection/IterableOnce.scala#L730) with `var x: A = null.asInstanceOf[A]` is useful where `A` is a type parameter because otherwise what would you assign to `x`?.

Comment: Is `null`  some kind of super type for all types?

Comment: @captain-yossarian It is a subtype of every other reference type. Starting Scala 3 it can be changed so that it is only a subtype of `Any` with `-Yexplicit-nulls` flag.